# Why do I keep getting 'Undefined variable: charities' in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I keep getting this undefined variable error. I am trying to display all the charities to the users, I am doing the exact same function for the 'charityowners' type of user and it is working for them.

Route:

```
Route::get('charities', 'HomeController@displayCharities');
```

Home Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Image;
use App\Charities;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function displayCharities()
    {
    $charities = Charities::all();

    return view('charities', ['charities' => $charities]);
    }

}
```

View:

```
<table class="table">

<tr>

    <td> <strong> Name </strong> </td>
    <td> <strong> Image </strong> </td>
    <td> <strong> Description </strong> </td>
    <td> <strong> Action </strong> </td>

</tr>

@foreach($charities as $charity)

<tr>

    <td> {{ $charity->name }} </td>
    <td> Not Available </td>
    <td> {{ $charity->description }} </td>

</tr>

@endforeach

</table>
```

The error I keep getting is:

> ErrorException in d9249250b321fd33ae875d6ca2417a0420928492.php line 39:
>   Undefined variable: charities (View: C:\wamp64\www\EasyDonationNew\laravel\resources\views\charities.blade.php)

What am I missing??

Comment: What do you get when you `dd($charities)` in your HomeController?

Comment: If you `dd($charities)` in your controller, does it contain anything?

Comment: @linktoahref hah great minds.

Comment: @linktoahref It returns the collection, an array of 4 items which correspond to the 4 charities in my database.

Comment: Have you tried `return view('charities', compact('charities'));` ?

Comment: @linktoahref Well, I honestly don't know what has happened, but I went to have dinner, came back and it's listing all my charities. Very strange.

Comment: Artificial Intelligence, maybe!

Comment: @linktoahref It's actually happened again, I don't understand because when I use 'dd' it returns the correct collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now by adding:

```
@if(isset($ownedCharities))
```

Before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
return view('charities')->with('charities', $charities);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try initializing the variable $charities globally as an empty string or as null.

On the global scope a var is only seen if it is defined.